# Prevent multiple selection in drop down menu

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.6

I am loading data into multiple selectboxes, I am using laravel with vuejs. Loading data into select box via vuejs but I need that there are no multiple selections in the select box.

My sample select box

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
        <select name="test[]" id="test[]" class="js-example-basic-single form-control" style="width: 100%;">
            <option value="">Select items</option>
            <option v-for="category in categories" :value="category.cat_id">@{{category.name}}</option>

        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control items" id="cat_price[]" name="cat_price[]">


    </td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
        <select name="test[]" id="test[]" class="js-example-basic-single form-control" style="width: 100%;">
            <option value="">Select items</option>
            <option v-for="category in categories" :value="category.cat_id">@{{category.name}}</option>

        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control items" id="cat_price[]" name="cat_price[]">


    </td>

</tr>
```

**JS Function**

```
$('#table1 tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('#test[]').change(function(){
        // alert($(this).val());
        if($('option[value='+$(this).val()+']:selected').length>1){
            alert('option is already selected');
            $(this).val($(this).find("option:first").val());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: create two computed properties using categories to populate select box and use javascript array filters to eliminate selected options from each computed properties. so as you select one option from a select box it will removed from the other select box

Comment: @Abhijith please explain your use case more precisely

Comment: i have 10 selectbox passing some values fromd database,i need to select a item from the first selectbox then when i select second select box i should not select a item that already selected in the first selectbox @boussadjrabrahim

Comment: the 10 selectboxes have the same list of items, i mean a selectbox duplicated 10 times ??

Comment: yes it have same id @boussadjrabrahim

Comment: Multiple elements with the same could cause some conflicts

Comment: I have been told to do so i did now they didn't want duplicate selection,is there any way to do it try lot ways but no luck @boussadjrabrahim

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.
`<option v-for="option in options" :disabled="selected.includes(option.value)" :value="option.value">`

Ref: [Vuejs disabled selected dropdown options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594885/vuejs-disabled-selected-dropdown-options?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: It's not working throws a blank page @Hardik Prajapati

Comment: If it’s not working and showing a blank page there should be console errors. Debug from the errors